# It is possible to execute MySQLi prepared statement before the other one is closed?

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement, php

Lets say I have a prepared statement. The query that it prepares doesn't matter. I fetch the result like above (I can't show actual code, as it is something I don't want to show off. Please concentrate on the problem, not the examples meaningless) and I get

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in... error. The error caused in the called object.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

class table2Info{
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct($_mysqli){
        $this->mysqli = $_mysqli;
    }

    public function getInfo($id)
    {
        $db = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT info FROM table2 WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1');
        $db->bind_param('i',$db_id);

        $db_id  = $id;

        $db->bind_result($info);
        $db->execute();
        $db->fetch();

        $db->close();

        return $info;
    }

}
$t2I = new table2Info($mysqli);

$stmt->prepare('SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s',$name);

$name = $_GET['name'];

$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->execute();

while($stmt->fetch())
{
    //This will cause the fatal-error
    echo $t2I->getInfo($id); 
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

The question is: is there a way to do another prepared statement while another one is still open? It would simplify the code for me. I can't solve this with SQL JOIN or something like that, it must be this way. Now I collect the fetched data in an array and loop through it after `$stmt->close();` but that just isn't good solution. Why should I do two loops when one is better?

Comment: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli bind\_param() fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582512/mysqli-bind-param-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

From the error you're getting it appears that your statement preparation failed.  [`mysqli::prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns a `MySQLi_STMT` object or `false` on failure.

Check for the return value from your statement preparation that is causing the error.  If it is false you can see more details by looking at `mysqli::error`.

Comment: It fails only when it is before the $stmt->close(). The problem is I don't see a way to do another prepared statement while other is open. The bind_param() inside the table2Info object trying to use the already open statement instead the one inside the object.