# stored procedure prepared statement bug mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Here's my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testProc`(IN num INT, INOUT num2 INT(11))
BEGIN
    set num2 = num+num2+7;
END
```

Here's the code that calls it:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'call testProc(?,?)')) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $type, $newId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo $newId;
    exit;
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_execute(): Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:1116) in
```

I don't understand. How can something so simple fail? I was just trying to work out how to get a value back from a prepared statement with a stored procedure when I ran up against this brick wall while trying to set up a simple example. Please help, because until I can solve this I can't provide an example so I can't get my real problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using bind_result after bind_param.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

and a previous stack overflow question: [mysqli bind_param() fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582512/mysqli-bind-param-fatal-error)

Comment: I tried adding a line: mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $type, $newId); but that just resulted in "mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement"

Comment: Ahah! I'd put the second bind before the execute. Now it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad! I was in the middle of writing code to make it easier to understand but got trapped in a meeting.