# PHP MySQLI Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bind_params()

Tags: php, mysqli

A friend of mine who isn't currently around massively helped on this script I am currently updating my old one however it is bringing up the following error message;

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bind_params()

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql ); 
    if (!$stmt) 
    { 
        die("Failed to prepare statement: " . $sql); 
    } 

    // here I only get the title, website, and summary from the <form> 
    // that posted to this page: 
    $title = $_POST["news_title"]; 
    $img  = $_POST["news_imgPath"]; 
    $desc  = $_POST["news_content"];
    $more  = $_POST["news_websitePath"];

    $stmt->bind_params("ssss", $title, $img, $desc, $more ); 

    if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) 
    { 
        die("Execution of bound statement failed: " . $stmt->error); 
    } 

    echo "Inserted {$stmt->affected_rows} correctly.<hr/>"; 

    $db->close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli bind\_param() fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582512/mysqli-bind-param-fatal-error)

Comment: @Joe Actually it's a typo so it's not the same problem

Comment: for future reference the docs for PHP mysqli are available online. reading through these would be a good first port of call when encountering errors like this. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bind_params()

**[bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)** , not `bind_params()`

```
                         ^
```

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled [bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $title, $img, $desc, $more );
```