# try to have PHP MYSQL query ignore empty variable in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

Post vars

```
$institute = $_POST['institute'];

if (isset($_POST['sections'])) {
    $sections = $_POST['sections'];
}

if (isset($_POST['division'])) {
    $division = $_POST['division'];
}

if (isset($_POST['level'])) {
    $level = $_POST['level'];
}

//check empty var
$where = "WHERE a.institute =?";
$bind = "i";
$prams = "$institute, ";
if (!empty($sections)) {
    $where .= "AND a.section = ?";
    $bind .= "i";
    $prams .= "$sections, ";
}

if (!empty($division)) {
    $where .= "AND a.division =?";
    $bind .= "i";
    $prams .= "$division, ";
}

if (!empty($level)) {
    $where .= "AND a.phase =?";
    $bind .= "i";
    $prams .= "$level";
}

//var_dump($institute, $sections, $division, $level);
var_dump($bind);

//$getSearch = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM student_basic_info WHERE institute =? AND section = ? AND division =?");
$getSearch = $db->prepare("SELECT
a.*, a.id AS stud_id, b.id, b.ins_name, c.id, c.sec_name, d.id, d.div_name
FROM student_basic_info AS a
JOIN institutes AS b ON (a.institute = b.id)
CROSS JOIN ins_sections AS c ON (a.section = c.id)
CROSS JOIN ins_division AS d ON (a.division = d.id)
$where GROUP BY a.id
");
$studSearch = array();
$getSearch->bind_param("'".$bind."'", $prams);
if ($getSearch->execute()) {
    $results = $getSearch->get_result();
    while ($vStud = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $studSearch[] = $vStud;
        ?>
```

got

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a
>   non-object on line 59

Line 59 is

```
$getSearch->bind_param("'".$bind."'", $prams);
```

after solving the problem of the `Call to a member function bind_param()`

now got `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables`

Comment: It seems that your _$getSearch_ is not an object. can you post the instanciation of this object ?

Comment: can you print $where?

Comment: yes I printed `$bind` and `$prams`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli bind\_param() fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582512/mysqli-bind-param-fatal-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$getSearch` is empty(false). Check your `prepare` function. It should return `true` on success.

```
if ($getSearch = $db->prepare(...)) {
    $getSearch->bind_param(...);
    ...
}
else {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $db->error);
}
```

Comment: thanks yes it says `Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?AND a.section = ?AND a.phase =? GROUP BY a.id' at line 7 ` will check it again

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces where you add your `AND` conditions; now your sql is invalid and the `prepare` will fail:

```
$where .= " AND a.section = ?";
           ^ here
// etc.
```

However, now your bind will fail, you cannot concatenate your values and send one long string as the second parameter. You need to bind each value individually.

Comment: can you please check this `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables` when I print the `bind` it's `iii` and when print the prams `931` what is the problem then

Comment: @YousefAltaf Like I mentioned, you need to bind each value individually so you would need another set of `if` condtions for the different situations.

Comment: but when var_dump `$where` got `string 'WHERE a.institute =? AND a.section =? AND a.phase =?' (length=52)` and when I var_dump `$bind` got `string 'iii' (length=3)` and when var_dump `$prams` got `string '9, 3, 1' (length=7)` where is the mistake

Comment: @YousefAltaf `$prams` is 1 string containing 3 values, you need 3 strings containing 1 value each. So 4 separate parameters for your bind function in this case.

Comment: pls can you edit your answer and show me how I can do this